# Adobe Dynamic Tag Management - Dynamic direct-call rules

Tags: dynamic, tags, adobe, google-tag-manager, adobe-analytics

We are using the data layer specfications from W3 (http://www.w3.org/2013/12/cedd..., which defines event data as an array of events. Not an issue for data elements accessing the last item in the array. The problem arrises when multiple events happen in quick sucession. Now when DTM goes goes to collect the event data the last event object in the array might not be the right one, and if two events are sent quickly the first event's data object is skipped and the last event's data object is used twice.

**Stategy 1**:
Creating many direct-call rules, one for each possible number of events and the data element for each rule accessing that item in the array:
_satillite.track('event_0')
_satillite.track('event_1')...

Not exactly fun to set up, still encounters the problem of perhaps having enough rules set up, and is not clean.

**Strategy 2**:
There's also a posibility of using data elements in the direct-call condition:
event_%event_number%

Not sure how using data-elements in the condition string would work.

**Strategy 3**
Use a FIFO queue to hold the keys for the order of the event and an object for which event in the data layer the event is.

```
var order_of_events = ['asdf', '1234'];
var events_number = {
  'asdf': 1,
  '1234': 2
};
```

Then send a direct-call event rule:

```
_satillite.track('event');
```

Then in the tag use Data Evements to query for the correct event data:

```
// Data Element code
// %next_eventName%
var event_key = getKey(); // returns first key in array
event_number = getValue(asdf); // returns 1
getEventName(event_number); // returns "Event Name"
```

How to notify the queue that the tag is done with the event details and to move the key out of the queue?

What strategy could be used to assure the correct event data object is used by the data element, any of the above, or has this problem already been tackled?

Comment: Can you provide a "real life" scenario for when "when multiple events happen in quick succession"? I can think of many, but from a tracking PoV this generally isn't a good thing to track and *usually* involves rethinking what you are tracking in the first place. For example, I've had clients ask to track whenever visitors hover over form elements, or track every % of page scroll.. this is usually a bad idea for numerous reasons. So firstly, can you please clarify what in particular you want to track?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:
Use the event object's eventInfo.eventAction key value. When you add an event in the array, you can call a generic _satllite.track('event_added') direct call rule. In your direct call rule, you can pull the events out of digitalData.events, loop over them and call a corresponding method in the direct call rule.

```
var eventActions={
  method1:function(event){
    //_satellite.track('method1');
    //or s.tl(event.eventInfo.eventName, true, 'hello world');
   //handle each event however you may like for analytics, testing, page manipulation etc.
  }
}

digitalData.events.forEach(function(item,index,arr){
  eventActions[item.eventInfo.eventAction](item);
});
```

This is what I was planning on doing but it may not suite your needs.